# How to merge project differences using visual source safe?

Tags: merge, visual-sourcesafe

We have two different projects on our source safe database (one of them is a copy of another one for some reasons there was a problem with our branching operation that didn't pin our branched files therefore I had to get a label and add it as a different project)
I know how I can see the differences between two projects and I know that there is a mechanism that let us merge differences into one file (I think "reconcile all" will do the trick but i am not sure)

So here's my question how can I merge a file in a project with another file from another project?

Comment: This may seem like something of a cop out, but the merge tool in VSS is crap. I'd pull both files, merge them with WinMerge, and then recheck the merged file into whichever project needed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSS (or as i call it, source destruction system) will destroy your code if you try to merge it using the built-in tools. Why does it do that ? .. because its a lame tool.

This is what i recommend

1. Get latest both branches.
2. Get the last version of the code
   before you branched. (just see the
   date and guess if you have to)
3. Do a 3-way merge because you have a
   base.
4. add the merged files into subversion
   (or something better than
   sourcesafe).

I have many old projects stored in sourcesafe. Its hopeless trying to use the built-in tools to do anything other than get latest, checkin and checkout.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I had the same solution in mind but I wanted to be sure there was no source safe solution available

Answer (score 1):

1. Checkout the latest version of the first VSS somewhere.
2. Create a repository using a different VCS tool (Subversion should be the most simple choice).
3. Import the project version into the new Subversion repo as a branch.
4. Checkout the latest  version of the *second* VSS **somewhere else**.
5. Import the project version into the new Subversion repo in a different branch.
6. Use any Subversion tools to merge the two branches.